# Unable to set cookie in nestjs, TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'color')

Tags: nestjs, fastify

Am trying to set property in session but getting undefined. Using NestJs + Fastify

**app.module.ts**

```
import { FastifyAdapter, NestFastifyApplication } from '@nestjs/platform-fastify';
// import fastifyCookie, { FastifyCookieOptions } from 'fastify-cookie'; --this was also not workin

const cookieSession = require( 'cookie-session' );

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
    AppModule,
    new FastifyAdapter( )
    );

  app.register( cookieSession( { 
    keys: [ 'asdsds' ]
  } ) );

  lines...
}
bootstrap();
```

**users.controller.ts**

```
imports...

export class UsersController {

    constructor( private usersService: UsersService, private authService: AuthService ) { }

    @Get( '/colors/:color' )
    setColor( @Param( 'color' ) color: string, @Session( ) session: any ) {
        // console.log( 'check ', session ); --> UNDEFINED
        session.color = color; --> Error HERE
        // session.set( color );
    }

    @Get( '/colors' ) 
    getColor( @Session( ) session: any ) {
        console.log( 'get session: ', session );
        return session.color;
    }
```

Error is:

```
[Nest] 41229  - 13/02/2022, 9:51:06 pm   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'color')
TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'color')
    at UsersController.setColor (/home/prabhat/Practice/Nest-Fastify/nestfastify/src/users/users.controller.ts:20:22)
    at /home/prabhat/Practice/Nest-Fastify/nestfastify/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-execution-context.js:38:29
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

**I have also tried with**

```
// app.register(fastifyCookie );
// app.register(fastifySession, {secret: 'a secret with minimum length of 32 characters'});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me is `fastify-secure-session` package, mentioned [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/session)

**Now my main.ts looks like:**

```
imports..
import secureSession from 'fastify-secure-session';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
    AppModule,
    new FastifyAdapter( )
    );

  app.register(secureSession, {
    secret: 'averylogphrasebiggerthanthirtytwochars',
    salt: 'mq9hDxBVDbspDR6n',
  });

  lines..
}
bootstrap();
```

**And app.controller.ts is:**

```
imports..
import * as secureSession from 'fastify-secure-session'

@Controller( 'auth' )
@MongooseClassSerializerInterceptor( UserDto )
export class UsersController {

    constructor( private usersService: UsersService, private authService: AuthService ) { }

    @Get( '/colors/:color' )
    setColor( @Param( 'color' ) color: string, @Session( ) session: secureSession.Session ) {
        console.log( 'check ', session );
        // session.color = color;
        session.set('color', color)
    }

    @Get( '/colors' ) 
    getColor( @Session( ) session: secureSession.Session ) {
        console.log( 'get session: ', session );
        // return session.color;
        return session.get( 'color' );
    }
   
}
```

**With this am able to set cookie, in NestJs with Fastify.**

Still interested in knowing why previous approach is not working for me as mentioned by *@Jay* in their answer.

Answer (score 0):

`cookie-session` is an express middleware. so if it's being used with fastify you'll probably end up with `req.raw.session` for the cookie.

`fastify-cookie` is a fastify specific package for *cookie* support, but not sessions directly, so you' need to use `req.cookie` or make a `@Cookie()` decorator

[`@fastify/session`](https://github.com/fastify/session) is the package for session support in fastify. By using `@fastify/session` with `fastify-cookie` you will have access to both `req.session` and `req.cookie`

Comment: Thanks! It's correct as I have mentioned I tried with fastify-cookie & session as well but in that case in subsequent request the session data is lost. So, I can add data but during retrieval am getting undefined/empty object.